# How to retrieve an OpenID Connect Identity Token from a cookie

Tags: c#, authentication, cookies, owin, openid-connect

How can I retrieve the OpenID connect token from the cookie(s) produced by Microsoft's OWIN-based middleware?

I am using `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies` and `Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect` to protect a website using an 'implicit flow'.  At times I think I might be able understand things better or be able to troubleshoot i I could inspect the "raw" token rather than the object model that gets produced from it.

I understand the information is stored via Cookie, but have not found how I can I retrieve the token from the cookie(s).  This is a development environment so I should have access to any certificates/secrets that are needed.

I understand that the token should have 3 segments separated by periods: `{header}.{claims}.{signature}`. If I can find the token I have learned that I can use [jwt.io](http://jwt.io/) to view the contents.  However, none of my cookies have contents matching that format.

This is the middleware configuration I am using:

```
app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType( CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType );
app.UseCookieAuthentication( new CookieAuthenticationOptions() );

app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
    new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
        ClientId = clientId,
        Authority = stsAuthority,
        RedirectUri = baseHostingPath,
        ResponseType = "id_token",
        Scope = string.Join( " ", "openid", "profile", "email" )
        } );
```

Answer (score 9):

If you want to do this just at debug time, I would suggest giving a try to https://github.com/vibronet/OInspector/tree/dev - it helps you to inspect the token in Fiddler.

If you want to do this in code, you can ensure that the raw token is saved in the ClaimsPrincipal by

- Adding

  ```
  TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
  { 
      SaveSigninToken = true 
  }
  ```

  to the options initialization
- Retrieving the token via something to the effect of

  ```
  var ci = (System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity)
               ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identity;
  string token = ((System.IdentityModel.Tokens.BootstrapContext)
                     ci.BootstrapContext).Token;
  ```